# Is it safe to call Realm.GetInstance(config) without Closing it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, realm

I am calling **Realm realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);** everytime I will execute a query. Is it safe to let it to be open throughout the application run without calling **realm.Close();** ?

Comment: Realm-Xamarin relies on `using()` blocks instead of Realm-Java's pattern of `try { } finally { close() }` so it implements disposable, Close isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

First, `Close` is obsolete, use `Dispose`.

```
[Obsolete("This method has been deprecated. Instead, dispose the realm to close it.")]
public void Close()
```

If you are creating a new `Realm` on *every* query, you **really** need to `Dispose`as soon as you can. It as it is keeping read version/locks on what you queried, consuming memory and possibility causing your Realm file to inflate in size due to other Realm instance writing to the same Realm file.

```
using (var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config))
{
    // Perform a query and do something with the results
}
```

or

```
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
// At some future point:
realm.Dispose();
```

Now re-using the ***same*** Realm instance across the life time of your app is fine, but you really should call `Dispose` when your app is closing (due to user interaction or the OS shutting it down...).

As a side note, if you are creating multiple `Realm` instances since you are using `Realm` instances on different threads due to awaited `Tasks`, you can take a look at [`RealmThread`](https://github.com/sushihangover/RealmThread)

> An Action/Task Message Pump for running commands on a dedicated Realm thread.

Disclaimer: `RealmThread` is a project of mine.

Comment: i used using but it gives me error saying this object belongs to a closed realm :)

Comment: @jace Yes, **managed** `RealmObject` or `RealmResult` are **"live"** objects from the realm object store. creating a Realm and Disposing of it at a later time when you no longer need the query results is fine, but I would highly advise against always creating a new Realm instance everytime you need execute a new query and thus keeping them all open. You would be much better off using a singleton pattern and re-using the same Realm instance for all your queries.

Comment: what if i am using GetInstance this way: var cat = Realm.GetInstance(config).All<RealmUserObject>(); . is it fine? or should I store it in Realm realm;? then use it as var cat = realm.All<RealmUserObject>();

Comment: in select statement, i am not closing it but in insert and delete, there is a close statement. btw i'll change it to dispose now

Comment: Use it the second way, store the Realm instance in a separate variable and use that to execute all your queries, inserts and deletes against the one...

Comment: what's the difference of two? sorry i'm just new to realm :)

Comment: In doing a `Realm.GetInstance(config).All<RealmUserObject>();` you are never closing that Realm instance, in fact you can not since you do not have a ref to it. Personally I would start simple, create a Realm instance and hold on to that Realm variable at the app level (as a singleton) or class level  instance variable and re-use that Realm instance for all your needs, inserts, deletes, and queries.

Comment: Thanks for your great time :) now looking at singleton :) storing to Realm realm is now clear to me :)

Comment: Remember, a Realm instance is an `IDisposable` and thus you are required to managed the life of that instance/object as Realm is using unmanaged resources (i.e. C++-based realm-core objects)

Comment: @jace No problem, if you have other questions/issues just post a new question, lots of Realm users and Realm's core C# developers read the `[Xamarin] [Realm]` tags